# Linq to sql query for check the usernames exists in table?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Any one please tell me how to a write query for **user is already exists or not** in a table using linq to sql and Entity Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool doesUserExist = myContext.Users.Any(u=>u.Username == "bob" && u.Password=="mypassword");
```

Comment: only need to check password of a user.if username was wrong return 201 error.if password was wrong need to return 202 error.